# How does checked and unchecked work on conversion in C#

Tags: c#

My question is about this code in a C# console programming I ask it with an example:

This code is impossible :

```
byte sum = (byte)(150 + 150); //impossible
```

but this code is possible :

```
byte sum = unchecked((byte)(150 + 150)); //possible
```

My question is: how does `unchecked` work? I mean how does `UNCHECKED` make this code possible?

Comment: C# statements can execute in either checked or unchecked context. In a checked context, arithmetic overflow raises an exception. In an unchecked context, arithmetic overflow is ignored and the result is truncated ..reference msdn

Comment: You are disabling the overflow checking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx

Comment: would you please explain me exactly with exsample? I will appreciate you. thanks.

Comment: thanks hardoc sallu Fan,your answer was exactly and great!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) means is if the value overflows (crosses over the `MaxValue` or `MinValue` boundary) no error is thrown and it allows the wrap-around to happen.

The `byte.MaxValue` is `255`, `150 + 150` is `300`. By allowing the overflow, it crosses over the `255` boundary and and starts counting again from `byte.MinValue` (`0` in this case) to reach a final value of `44` (`(150 + 150) - 256 = 44`)

Answer (score 3):

> The overflow can be detected at compile time because all the terms of
>   the expression are constants.

If you replace this with

```
int i = 150;
byte sum = (byte)(i + i);
```

**It will compile fine.**

By using [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx), you are `suppressing overflow-checking`.

Even this won't compile -

```
const int i = 150;
byte sum = (byte)(i + i);
```

because of `const` keyowrd usage which makes it available at compile time.